# Problemas con MariaDB, consulta lenta

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

En el servidor tengo dos bases de datos.
produccionDB y produccionDB_test, las dos son iguales en campos, tablas, relaciones, etc, ya que con produccionDB_test se hacen pruebas.
El problema se presenta cuando quiero hacer en PHPMYADMIN una simple consulta, un select con dos condiciones.
En la de producción trae 150 registros y en la de pruebas trae 183 registros, para comparar el tiempo de ejecución de la consulta en las dos bases de datos.
En la de producción, la cual utilizan los usuarios constantemente demora en traer los 150 registros al rededor de 8 segundos y la de pruebas demora 1 segundo.
Mi pregunta es:
¿No deberían demorar un tiempo muy similar, ya que es el mismo servidor el que responde?
¿Cuál es el problema y posible solución?

Comment: Por lo que comentas, están como index los campos que consultas? utilizas laves primarias ?

Comment: claro, las llaves foráneas son primarias en otras tablas, el problema principal es que una consulta en la bd de producción demora más que en la bd de pruebas, estoy probando con una consulta sencilla en PHPMYADMIN y en el de producción demora 7 segundos más la consulta que en el de pruebas

Comment: @JeisonGonzalez Puedes ejecutar el commando SHOW CREATE TABLE <nombre_tablas> por cada una de las tablas implicadas? Tambien mostrarnos la consulta que haces? Puedes indicarnos la version de MySQL/MariaDB que usas? Las especificaciones del servidor?

Answer (score 0):

Una consulta lente puede deberse a varios factores.

La cantidad de registros totales de la tabla, aunqeu te muestro unos 150-183 registros puede que en una BBDD tengas mas de 10.000 registros y en la otra unos 1.000, La consulta tiene que recorrer todos los registros igualmente. ¿Cual es la cantidad de registros que tienes en cada tabla?

Los registros pueden estas bloqueados por consultas de otros usuarios, cuando un usuario consulta un registro ese registro se bloquea, y hasta que no tiene todos los datos no lo desbloquea y por lo tanto en ese tiempo no esta disponible, y eso puede retrasar la consulta. Yo probaría la BBDD de producción en un entorno si mas usuarios, para ver si ese es el problema.